# OpenXML SDK remove image from PowerPoint Slide

Tags: .net, vb.net, openxml-sdk

I have am manipulating a Power Point slide using OpenXML SDK. The slide has one image on it. What I am trying to do is if a particular image is found on the server replace the slides image with the one found on the server, otherwise delete the image completely.

I have the replacement working fine but if I try to delete the image I still get an image control with "This image can not be displayed" in it.

Here is what I am doing to delete the image, note slidePart is the slide I am manipulating:

```
'get the first image on the slide
Dim blip As Drawing.Blip = slidePart.Slide.Descendants(Of Drawing.Blip)().First()
blip.Remove()
slidePart.Slide.Save()
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Any advice would be appreciated, thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look for the `Picture` element that corresponds to your image and delete that element.  I tend to search by the image name in order to find the `Picture` element and then just delete it.  Here's a C# sample of the code I use:

```
Picture imageToRemove = slidePart.Slide.Descendants<Picture>().SingleOrDefault(picture => picture.NonVisualPictureProperties.OuterXml.Contains(imageFileName));

if (imageToRemove != null)
{
    imageToRemove.Remove();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The slide only has one image on it, I tried the following: `Dim imageToRemove As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture = slidePart.Slide.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture)().SingleOrDefault()` but I am getting nothing in return. I shouldn't have to search by image name if there is only one image should I?

Comment: The `Picture` element is located as a child of `slidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree` so try searching there for the element. You shouldn't have to search by the filename if you only have one picture.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture = slidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture)().SingleOrDefault()` but am still getting nothing back.